# Mongoose many to many relationship with additional data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Product Schema:

```
var ProductSchema = new Schema({
    productName: {type: String, required: true},
});
```

Client schema:

```
var ClientSchema = new Schema({
    clientName: {type: String, required: true},
    products: [{ type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Product'}],
});
```

How can I add additional fields to the relationship? For example add field **quantity**:

```
var ClientSchema = new Schema({
    clientName: {type: String, required: true},
    products: [{ type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Product', quantity: Number}],
});
```

Comment: What do you mean? What is `quantity` and how do you think it will be maintained by the database?